# Different collections based on status in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a transactions table which contain a status field.
Status can be Completed, Cancelled and Ongoing.
Will it be helpful if I separate the the transaction table into three separate tables namely OngoingTrans, CompletedTrans, CancelledTrans.

Such behavior is helpful in relational database but will it be helpful in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

As per the white paper on MongoDB best practices provided at mongodb.com
[MongoDB Best practices](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-performance-best-practices)

> **Avoid negation in queries.** Like most database systems,
>   MongoDB does not index the absence of values and
>   negation conditions may require scanning all documents. If
>   negation is the only condition and it is not selective (for
>   example, querying an orders table where 99% of the
>   orders are complete to identify those that have not been
>   fulfilled), all records will need to be scanned.

They have suggested not to use negation in queries so its good to store it separately